# Add objects to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
"__v":0,
"_id":"526a7b9c1affd1401d000001",
"ranStr":"azsuC2Ers0qTEcpzS8Jrs1pZ7MQH0goa",
"userId":{
        "username":"t",
        "_id":"51e11b28418dcfd01f000002"
},
"meta":{
    "numberComments":0,
    "favs":0,
    "views":112
},
"enddate":"2014-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
"startdate":"2013-10-25T00:00:00.000Z",
"comments":[],
"categories":[],
"fileurl":[],
"telephone":"1234567890"
}
```

When I add an object to it:

```
 addObj[obj.length] = saveobject;
```

the previous content gehts replaced.

When I make an array out of it and push the object:

```
 addObj = [loadedJSON];
 addObj.push(saveObj);
```

I get this after the first

```
 [Object]
```

after the second so fare so good

```
 [Object, Object]
```

and after the third it gets messed up

```
[Array(2), Object]
```

What do I miss?

I hope some one can help with this?

The way I hoped it would look like is this.

```
 [Object, Object, Object, ...and so on]
```

**EDIT**

to be More specific
when I add a new Object I load the JSON file in a variable and then I try to add the new Object.

Which works for the first two objects but the third one is added to the first object so that I got this result.

```
[Array(2), Object]
```

I dont want it nested like this! But how do I get it like this?

```
[Object, Object, Object].
```

**EDIT**

So eventually you all were right I just mixed up the array when i loaded it the second time every thing is fine now thank for pointing me in the right direction.

on the first time:

```
  var a= [];
  var b= {};
  b= 'some things';
  a.push(b);
```

and wenn a.length != null

```
  b= 'the rest';
  a.push(b);
```

and now everything is just as expected!

Comment: That is not "a JSON". There is no such thing as "a JSON". "JSON" is to be used as an adjective to describe the format of a string or file, not as a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, this has nothing to do with JSON.

It seems you want to have an array storing successive instances of a given object (that happens to have been encoded in JSON at some point, but for the problem at hand we could not care less).

First, create a sorage array.
Then push each new instance into it.

```
var storage = []; // your storage array, initially empty

// ....

while (some_guy_wants_to_send_me_something ())
{
    var new_object = get_what_the_guy_sent_me_that_happens_to_be_JSON_encoded();
    storage.push (new_object); 
}
```

EDIT:

If you use a button:

```
var storage = []; // your storage array, initially empty

// ....

function add_whatever_object ()
{
    var new_object = get_what_the_guy_sent_me_that_happens_to_be_JSON_encoded();
    storage.push (new_object); 
}

// HTML

<button type="button" onclick='add_whatever_object();'>
```

I still don't see where the catch is.

Comment: I add them via button! The first two objects are added correctly but after this all the others added to the first as nested objects in an array...

Answer (score 1):

check the if it is an array:

```
Array.isArray(loadedJSON) //true
```

do this:

```
loadedJSON.push(saveObj);
```

if it was not an array push it to an array:

```
var myarray = [];
myarray.push(loadedJSON);
```

an then push your other object:

```
myarray.push(saveObj);
```

an so on:

```
myarray.push(otherObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear on what you actually want, but based on a little speculation I was able to write the following code for you. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
var a ={
"__v":0,
"_id":"526a7b9c1affd1401d000001",
"ranStr":"azsuC2Ers0qTEcpzS8Jrs1pZ7MQH0goa",
"userId":{
        "username":"t",
        "_id":"51e11b28418dcfd01f000002"
},
"meta":{
    "numberComments":0,
    "favs":0,
    "views":112
},
"enddate":"2014-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
"startdate":"2013-10-25T00:00:00.000Z",
"comments":[],
"categories":[],
"fileurl":[],
"telephone":"1234567890"
};

var b ={
"__v":0,
"_id":"526a7b9c1affd1401d000001",
"ranStr":"azsuC2Ers0qTEcpzS8Jrs1pZ7MQH0goa",
"userId":{
        "username":"t",
        "_id":"51e11b28418dcfd01f000002"
},
"meta":{
    "numberComments":0,
    "favs":0,
    "views":112
},
"enddate":"2014-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
"startdate":"2013-10-25T00:00:00.000Z",
"comments":[],
"categories":[],
"fileurl":[],
"telephone":"1234567890"
};

var c ={
"__v":0,
"_id":"526a7b9c1affd1401d000001",
"ranStr":"azsuC2Ers0qTEcpzS8Jrs1pZ7MQH0goa",
"userId":{
        "username":"t",
        "_id":"51e11b28418dcfd01f000002"
},
"meta":{
    "numberComments":0,
    "favs":0,
    "views":112
},
"enddate":"2014-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
"startdate":"2013-10-25T00:00:00.000Z",
"comments":[],
"categories":[],
"fileurl":[],
"telephone":"1234567890"
};
var ObjArr = [];

ObjArr.push(a);
ObjArr.push(b);
ObjArr.push(c);

console.log(ObjArr);
```

Here is the fiddle to it => http://jsfiddle.net/rB3Un/

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but i already tried this, I edited my Question to be hopefully more specific!